# how to stop threads that are in a blocking wait?

Tags: java, multithreading, freeze

Since thread.stop() is deprecated in Java, what is the proper way to deal with blocking waits that are never going to finish?

For example, when running a server-client model with many clients, my server code may look like:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(accept){
            try {
                /* attempt to read a single message */
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                Message m = (Message) is.readObject();
                /* delegate message to appropriate handler */
                MessageDelegator.getInstance().delegate(m);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } 
        }
    }
}.start();
```

However, the listening process here is blocking, so the classical trick of setting `accept=false;` will not work here (a client may perpetually not send anything, resulting in a perpetually hanging thread). How can I kill this thread if I'm no longer allowed to use `thread.stop()`?

Comment: Close the stream/socket.

Comment: How should I close the stream? Should I make the ObjectInputStream accessible from other threads and then do `threadToKill.is=null;` or something? I'm probably misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: No. Setting a reference to null doesn't close the stream. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29.

Comment: And closing the stream from another thread will release the blocking `readObject()` method? That is not clear to me from the API.

Comment: Read paragraph 7.1.6 of http://books.google.fr/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT151&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false, which is the de facto reference regarding concurrency in Java.

Comment: For reference purposes I've printscreened that section from the book and paste it here (as google books seems to change its preview pages now and then): http://imgur.com/zYnwEWc

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: Hmm... `readObject` doesn't seem to throw `InterruptedException` though, which I assume means it doesn't listen to interrupts? Or how could I see in the API that this is going to work?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if it ends up throwing an `IOException`.  Try it.  Also, what is the concrete type of the stream you're reading?